# MultiLoc2 (sub-cellular localization )error

Tags: python

i am trying to use MultiLoc2 and facing this problem. i am following step by step manual and in the final command i got this error.

```
raise Error("Configuration Error: A path is not set. Run configure script!")
util.Error: 'Configuration Error: A path is not set. Run configure script!'
```